# Excel search upwards from cell for first result meeting a criteria

Tags: excel, search, excel-formula

Alright I have a bit of a weird problem:

I have a store, that sells Cookies, Cakes and Wine.

I also have a report on excel for what products were sold in a day. Looks something like this:

```
| ID | Product Name | Quantity Sold |
| --- |--- | --- |
| Cookies| | |
| 1 |Ginderbread | 2 |
| 2 |Chocolate chip| 5 |
| 3 |Cookie type C | 1|
| Cakes | | |
```

From this report my goal is to get a table looking like this:

```
| ID | Name | Quantity Sold | Category |
| --- |--- | --- | --- |
```

All I need to do is get the Category from above the records, to inside the records.

However, there's 1 restriction: I can't manually enter the Category. I **must** use some formula to find out what the category is.

1 idea I have thought of is to use a VLookup with the range being from the first row to the current row. But having trouble figuring out making it search for "Cookies", "Cakes" and "Wine" all at once then returning whichever it finds first (from bottom up)

Should be noted neither Product Name or ID are unique keys. Yes, I hate it as much as you do.

Comment: What version of Excel?  Can you use VBA or PowerQuery?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld The version is Excel from Office 365.

Comment: @JvdV So is it not possible to use something like a VLookup to search from the current cell to the top of the table for "Cookie, Cake, Wine" and returning the value of whatever comes first?

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. I misread your table. Deleted my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your ID's are unique:

For the ID column:

```
=FILTER(A:A,ISNUMBER(A:A))
```

For the Name column:
`=VLOOKUP(E2,$A:$S,2)` (and fill down)

For the Category Column:

```
=LET(x,FILTER($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(E2,$A:$A,0)),$A$2:INDEX($A:$A,1+MATCH(E2,$A:$A,0))="ID"),y,COUNTA(x),INDEX(x,y))
```

(and fill down)

- To return the category

  - `MATCH` the Id number to get the last row number to check in the first column
  - Create a filter that only returns the row which says ID
  - Use that filter criteria against a range that is offset by one (up) which will return an array of just the categories
  - Return the last item in that array

[image]

Comment: Sorry, the IDs and Product Names are not unique. Didn't expect it to come up so didn't add it originally.

Comment: @Sargent179 If neither are unique, I'd suggest you develop a VBA or Power Query solution.  It'll be much easier to maintain.

Comment: Apologies, realized there was a misunderstanding about my goal. I just need to stick the Category into the records instead of above them.
Afterwards I was just going to remove the Quantity Column and copy/paste the data across before deleting the "Cakes, Cookies, Wine" rows and keeping only 1 of the header rows.